# How were elders addressed in Ancient Egypt?

Tags: ancient-history, social-history, egypt

I’m writing a book and want to know how a child would respectfully address an older male and female person—like Sir or Lord or Madam—in Ancient Egypt?

Comment: Cannot provide an answer to the question, but a remark in Herodotus ([History, 2.80](https://www.sacred-texts.com/cla/hh/hh2080.htm)) on relations between old and young Egyptians might be useful: `the Egyptians are in agreement with some of the Hellenes, namely with the Lacedemonians, but not with the rest, that is to say, the younger of them when they meet the elder give way and move out of the path, and when their elders approach they rise out of their seat.` Also: `instead of addressing one another in the roads they do reverence, lowering their hand down to their knee`.

Comment: Ancient Egypt spanned thousands of years. Which kingdom or period are you interested in? Where have you looked already? Please help us to help you.